# Issue casting with .class in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I thought that .class was the class of the object it was being called on. However this does not fit with what I was trying to do with a program. I'll give some examples.

```
//o is of type Object
//this method throws error "cannot find symbol" for the cast method
SampleClass.cast(o);
```

```
//sampleClass is an instance of SampleClass
//this method throws error "<identifier> expected"
sampleClass.class.cast(o);
```

```
//this method works!
SampleClass.class.cast(o);
```

```
//this returns two "<identifier> expected" errors
sampleClass.class.class.cast(o);
```

```
//this works too!
((SampleClass) o)
```

I previously thought that sampleClass.class == SampleClass, an object of type Class. I also thought that SampleClass.class would return something really meta that's hard to think about. Now I know that I don't really know anything. Any help solving this conundrum is appreciated :)

Edit: Thanks everyone! I'm happy to be learning this about Java. I'm grateful for the help

Comment: `SampleClass.class` is an instance of `Class<SampleClass>`. It is a representation of `SampleClass` as an object, rather than another way of saying `SampleClass`. A class is not an object in Java.

Comment: `sampleClass.class.class` will just return `Class<Class>` because it is the class that represents class objects.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong: I think you meant to write that `sampleClass.getClass().getClass()` will return `Class<Class>`. The OP is correct that `sampleClass.class.class` gives a compile-error.

Comment: Side note: If you can use `((SampleClass) o)`, that is the best (most legible, likely most performant) way. The rest is more useful when you are messing around with things like reflection and don't know which types your objects will actually have at compile time.

Comment: @ruakh *facepalm* yes thank you. Can't ask an instance for it's class object without a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have put together some compilable Java code that can maybe clarify some usage of Class and casting. Hopefully it is self-documenting enough.

You can think of `Sample.class` as a "class literal" in the same way `"something"` is a string literal. It is an expression, it has a value, it is assignable to a variable, it is an object. The *type* of this object is `Class<Sample>`. On the other hand `Sample` is a type, not an expression, you cannot assign it to a variable.

`Class` is a meta-class, i.e. it is a class which desribes another class. You cannot go more meta than `Class<Class> classClass = Class.class;`. Interesting thing: there are also primitive class literals like `int.class`.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // class literal
        Class<Sample> sampleClassLiteral = Sample.class;

        final Sample superObject = new Sample();
        // dynamic class
        // `? extends Sample` because the dynamic type could be a subclass
        Class<? extends Sample> superClassMethod = superObject.getClass();
        // classes are comparable both by == and equals, because `Class` is final and it does not override the default equals implementation
        assert sampleClassLiteral == superClassMethod;
        assert sampleClassLiteral.equals(superClassMethod);

        Sample subObject = new SubSample();
        // dynamic class can be different from the static type of the variable
        Class<? extends Sample> subSampleMethod = subObject.getClass();
        assert subSampleMethod != superClassMethod;

        SubSample staticCast = ((SubSample) subObject);

        List<Object> listOfAny = List.of(superObject, subObject, sampleClassLiteral, "some string", 12);
        // static type check & casting
        final List<Sample> listOfSample = listOfAny.stream()
                .filter(elem -> elem instanceof Sample) // Sample.class::isInstance
                .map(elem -> (Sample) elem)             // Sample.class::cast
                .collect(toList());

        final List<Sample> samples = listOfTargetClass(listOfAny, Sample.class);
        final List<? extends Sample> sameAsSamples = listOfTargetClass(listOfAny, superClassMethod);
        // [superObject, subObject] : does NOT contain `sampleClassLiteral` because it's not of type `Sample`, it is of type `Class<Sample>`
        System.out.println(samples);
        System.out.println(sameAsSamples);
        assert samples.equals(sameAsSamples);

        final List<SubSample> subSamples = listOfTargetClass(listOfAny, SubSample.class);
        System.out.println(subSamples);
    }

    static <T> List<T> listOfTargetClass(Collection<?> anyCollection, Class<T> targetClass) {
        // dynamic type check and casting
        return anyCollection.stream()
                .filter(targetClass::isInstance) // obj -> targetClass.isInstance(obj)
                .map(targetClass::cast) // obj -> targetClass.cast(obj)
                .collect(toList());
    }

    static class Sample { }

    static class SubSample extends Sample { }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I previously thought that sampleClass.class == SampleClass, an object of type Class.

You were very close. The correct understanding is that `sampleClass.getClass() == SampleClass.class`, an instance of the class `Class`.

`SampleClass` itself is a type, not a value. (In Java that's a firm distinction.)

Comment: To be precise, `SampleClass.class` is an instance of `Class<SampleClass>`, if we want to pay attention to our generics.

Comment: @Taschi: Right. I wasn't sure how best to express it, since `sampleClass.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends SampleClass>` and `SampleClass.class` has type `Class<SampleClass>`, but they're the same instance, and due to erasure the runtime-type is just `Class`. So I punted and copied the OP's phrasing. I'll give some thought to how I can word it better.